# Can you make pasta dough in a breadmaker?

Tags: equipment, dough, pasta

Is it a good idea to buy a breadmaker instead of a food processor for making pasta dough (and bread, obviously)?

Comment: And can you make bread in a pasta-maker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the bread maker, zojirushi latest model can make udon and their recipe book that comes with it contains fresh pasta recipes, as to the quality of that pasta, that would come down to the quality of the ingredients you use and the temperature of the dough during the kneading process. Also zojirushi's bread machines have customizable settings (except for temperature(you can pick crust darkness but not temperature to exact degree) and knead strength). The machine has it's issues, such as it's nonstick kneading and baking vessel wears which should not happen if you only use it for kneading dough. So by no means am I advocating you get a bread maker, save your money for a good stand mixer or do it the old fashioned way if you have the time and energy.

Answer (score 16):

No. Pasta dough is much firmer than bread dough and could possibly break the machine or the blade.

Comment: I don't agree; I often use bread machines to make pasta, and they turn out great. No firmness has ever been a problem; if it's too dry, you get dry clumps or dough; any wetter and you get anything from a firm dough to a soft one.

Answer (score 9):

Neither a bread maker nor a food processor are the best tools for this job. Most pastas are traditionally made on a countertop, mixing by hand.  Feel is often important as one gauges hydration.  A stand mixer  can also be used, as they have the power and attachments to mix these typically stiffer doughs.

Comment: Food processors work fine for pasta.  The thing is, you don’t over fill it, and you add just enough water until it forms a ball and then it beats the ball against the side of the food processor.  (My mom is third generation Sicilian American, and this is how she always made lasagne noodles). Some food processors specifically have a plastic ‘kneading’ blade, but the metal one will still work

Answer (score 2):

I had a bread machine once that could make pasta—I can't judge how well, not being a connoisseur. As I recall there was a generic mixing setting that did a better job than I could with a fork.